# What's the noun for the result of an iteration?

Tags: terminology, comments

I'm commenting some code right now, and I'm looking for a word meaning the thing being iterated over. *Iterator* is an object performing an *iteration*, but what's the object that the iterator is iterating; the result of one iteration?

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/on-the-troubles-of-naming-and-terminology

Comment: @gnat Question is looking for a standard term for a well known concept, so should be accepted per the quoted discussion, imo

Comment: In C#, it's simply called the **iteration variable.**  *[During execution of a foreach statement, the iteration variable represents the collection element for which an iteration is currently being performed.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664754(v=vs.71).aspx)*

Comment: @Jules and how are we going to find out what's standard? by [polling the readers](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6491#6491)? by how much likes / dislikes they will give to answers [like this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/310191/31260)

Comment: I was about to say the same thing as @Jules. The general idea of iteration originates from mathematics, so I'd say it's a pretty well-known concept, which should have fixed and well-defined terminology. This question is not primarily opinion-based, and I don't think it's off-topic.

Comment: I can't find anything as a search result for 'iterand' and 'perl' or 'java'.  And 'iterand' isn't even mentioned on the [Wikipedia page for iterator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator).  There doesn't appear to be a standard term for this, and it doesn't appear to be a well known concept. It might be such in academic discussion (and behind paywalls apparently) - but this isn't anything that people talk about.  Its a loop variable. The index. But I get blank looks from *all* of my coworkers when asking them what an iterand is.  Shoot, it even comes up as an unknown word as I type it.

Comment: It also appears to be called an "iteration variable" in Python, C++ Java, D, Rust...

Comment: ... Ecmascript 6 ...

Comment: I hereby propose "iteree".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/716238/distinction-between-iterator-and-enumerator

Comment: You iterate over an enumerator

Comment: @MatthewWhited, I'd say you iterate over an enumeration using and iterator or enumerator

Comment: Enumeration is not the same as an Enumerator.

Comment: Although conceptualy there is a 'thing you are iterating' is there actualy one in reality? Surely the compiled code will be performing a while loop. Calling a function untill the result of that function fails some check

Comment: Hence 'iteration variable' which in my view refers to the i in 'for(int i...'

Comment: An enumerator is what is used to enumerate over an enumeration. Enumeration is also the name of the process of enumerating over an enumeration, with an enumerator. English is kind of a horrible language. Regardless, enumeration isn't necessarily the same thing as iteration. An iterator iterates over a collection of objects, and an enumerator enumerates the objects in a collection.

Comment: You iterate over an `iterable` no?

Comment: @MetaFight, `iterable` is an adjective, describing something that can be iterated over, usable as a noun by English idioms; not the concurrent variable that iteration exposes. Unless it's considered a portmanteau of `iteration` and `variable`, which I think could cause (or be caused by) some confusion. 

@RobertHarvey, if you post your comments as answers, with citations for each (or at least a few) of your statements, I'd probably accept that as the answer. Although I'm personally going to start using the word `iterand`, so get ready to start saying it when the trend catches on ;)

Comment: @MikeNakis, I think that would get confused with [`iteratee`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteratee).

Comment: @MichaelHoffmann my bad, I hadn't parsed your question correctly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### ***Iterand***

I've seen this term used in some scholarly publications online (Google search results that link to pages I don't want to pay to access), but I can't find any etymology or published definition of it.

Hopefully someone else has a more thorough answer.

***Update, years later***

It looks like at least one language (Chapel) has documentation that uses the term *iterand*:

> Chapel's for-loops (and their parallel counterparts, coforall and forall) can be driven by multiple iterands in a coordinated manner known as zippered iteration. This is expressed using the zip keyword, followed by a parenthesized list of the iterands.

https://chapel-lang.org/docs/users-guide/base/zip.html

Answer (score 3):

The Java API uses [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) as the name of the interface that produces an `Iterator`.  The docs for `Iterator` refer to the object of each iteration as an ***element***.

Comment: Any answer not starting with "other" or "enum" gets an upvote from me.  "Element" is a bit too specific in the general case of something like an ES6 generator, but fits most of the cases and is clear and concise for the most common case of looping through an array or collection.